# Validate that the HttpClient is retrying requests

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I just learned about the DefaultHttpRequestRetryHandler last night and I'm trying to play around with it and verify that I've set it up correctly and it does retry requests. How can I verify (either by seeing log messages or setting up a (unit) test or making a specific call?

For the record, here's my code:

```
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpRequestRetryHandler;

DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
httpClient.setHttpRequestRetryHandler(new DefaultHttpRequestRetryHandler(3, true));
```

I've tried changing the URL to an endpoint that doesn't exist, changing the port, changing the resource location, but I can't seem to get a timeout and I can't see the code trying to retry the request.

Primarily, I'm making HTTP calls to a REST endpoint and I'd like to retry in the case of timeout.  However if I get some additional functionality and handling that I didn't know I should be doing, I'm happy to get other benefits for free as well.

Answer (score 0):

Please look in the [docs](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpRequestRetryHandler.html#DefaultHttpRequestRetryHandler%28int,%20boolean%29) for that. Not all exceptions are retried. By default:
`InterruptedIOException`, `UnknownHostException`, `ConnectException`,`SSLException`

Your attempts at bad host/port will likely cause unknown host so not retried. You need a timeout to happen. Use a proxy like Charles or Fiddler. Or use use the other overloaded constructor and provide your own empty exception list.